# cant convert urdf to sdf in gazebo 7.4

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Before when i used to use command "`gzsdf print urdfname.urdf > newname.sdf`" it used to succesfully convert urdf file to sdf, but now its now working and error is coming saying `gzsdf: command not found`. I am using ros indigo, ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15032/cant-convert-urdf-to-sdf-in-gazebo-7.4/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Shouldn't it have a space between `gz` and `sdf`?

`gz sdf -h`

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1